# Relational condition in mongodb

Tags: sql, mongodb, mongoid, nosql

Suppose I have a mongodb collections A and B. 
While A has a foreign key to B called b_id.

How do I do in MongoDB (or even in ruby is better) the following query:

```
select * from A where b_id not in (select id from B where <some_condition> );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't do relational queries (it's not called *NoSQL* without cause) -- but there are other ways you can accomplish this.

1. Run a two-step query in your Mongo client, first getting the inner array, then using the [$nin operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24nin):

   var ids = db.B.find( conditions );
   db.A.find( { b_id: { $nin: ids } } );
2. If you're still in the design phase you can consider using nested documents for your schemas.  For example, if **B** has many **A**, then you could add an array of **A** to each **B** as a property.  (Keep in mind, though, that there is a [limit to document size in MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents), so this is not a good solution if the number of **A** in any given **B** could be very large.)

Comment: Thank You. I can't embed that object it should stay alone. But I'll try the first option.